# WHS - Windows Update Failure

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, networking, windows-home-server

Clicking "Update Now..." inside my EX470 control panel for Windows Update produces the following error message:

"Windows Home Server updates installation can not complete.  Please try again later.  If the problem persists, please restart the server."

I have rebooted the server numerous times, and I have also used remote desktop to connect to the machine to perform the update this way, however the browser is unable to pull up http://windowsupdate.microsoft.com.   This is very strange behavior because I am able to access all other sites (gmail.com, serverfault.com, etc).

Would it be possible for someone to explain to me how I can check to see what is blocking the connection of this device, which apparently has a valid internet connection, to the Microsoft Windows Update site?

*note #1  Using the shortcut: %SystemRoot%\system32\wupdmgr.exe  does not work either.  It says "Connecting to 65.55.200.155..." but nothing ever happens.  This is strange because all other sites seem fine.  Also, I can connect to windowsupdate.microsoft.com on my local desktop so I know this is running as well*

Answer (score 1):

Not sure WTF happened, but it appears to have been an intermittent error.

Answer (score 1):

If you remote desktop into the server you should be able to go into Control Panel -> Admin Tools -> Event Viewer.

Look through the Application and System logs around the time that your updates failed, you should see sets of MsiInstaller, Windows Update Agent and NTServicePack events around the time that your install failed. Have a look at what those say, and any other events logged at the same time, this should give you more info.

Answer (score 0):

i got the same thing and it was becasue i forgot to set the time and date for WHS. date was set to june 2000 7:25pm and it was actually june 21st 2010 2:00pm. its installing about 94 updates at the moment. yeah yeah old post blah blah but heres the fix :)